# 1 Print Job to Multiple Receipt Printers

Tags: printing, printer, bluetooth, network-printer

I have 4 Bluetooth printers. I can get them all to print the same orders using Print Distributor - simple and elegant solution.

The problem is that the print jobs come from a single tablet. The Bluetooth signal cannot get to the virtual printer set up by Print Distributor, to direct the job to the multiple printers.

How can I get my Bluetooth print command (from a tablet) into a virtual printer in a Windows PC?